# Why is Thymeleaf returning a String from my HashMap?

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf and Spring. I have a page on which I want to populate some fields and I'm passing in a `Map` object to the page model using `model.addAttribute` as below. `pbObject` is a `PassbackObject` that we're using to pass data between form pages.

```
Map<String, Object> formData = new HashMap<>();
formData.put("station", station);
pbModel.setFromPriorForm(formData);
model.addAttribute("pbObject", pbModel);
System.out.println("The station object is: " + formData.get('station'));
System.out.println("The class of the Station object is: " + formData.get("station").getClass());
```

The two print statements return the `station` object and `org.unavco.web.response.obj.Station` as expected so the object types are fine here.

The problem arises when I try to access the Map object in Thymeleaf.

```
<input th:value="${pbObject.fromPriorForm.get('station').getClass()}"/>
```

The above code populates the input field with `class java.lang.String`. **It's not a String!!! It's a Station!** And yes, it's seeing the correct data because if I remove `.getClass()` I see the correct data (apparently as a String). I need to be able to access the object attributes later on so a String won't cut it. Why is Thymeleaf casting my mapped object to a String? How can I make it preserve the original object class?

Comment: HTML values will always be strings. No?

Comment: @holmis83 Maybe that is how this works but `getClass()` is definitely a Java method and it returns a Java class type so Thymeleaf is doing some Java stuff back there. I don't fully understand how Thymeleaf talks to Spring though.

Comment: Have you tried mapping the values of your object into a hidden class and setting your form th:object="pbObject type" then, when you return it back as a ModelObject, the model will populate an object using the framework you specified.